How to create 3D collider form what tile(from tilemap) is underneath?
I have 2D top down game(where Z replaces Y), but uses 3D colliders, rigidbodys, and Vector3. I added a tilemap, having 1 layer for ground and a layer for walls. Since the tilemapCollider2d is only 2d what are my options for adding a 3d collider above a wall tile.
I tried searching online but couldn't find people with the same problem.

Is the tilemap a 2D graphic with tiles pictures on it or a 3D model with tile meshes on it? Or are your tiles individual 2D graphics or individual 3D meshes?

@Agustin0987 its the unity tilemap componet, with GO with grid componet as parent, and im using tile pallete to place 2d sprites

Oh I see, well I'm sorry to say that I am not familiar with the tilemap component, so I don't think I can give you useful input on how to use it. Apologies.
